# Docker versioning is different on Ubuntu and on CentOS

Tags: docker, ubuntu, centos

I've installed the latest version of docker on CentOS7 and Ubuntu18.04.
However, the versions displayed are as follows.

On Ubuntu:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d
```

On CentOS:

```
# docker --version
Docker version 1.13.1, build 7f2769b/1.13.1
```

Can I assume that these are more or less the latest versions functionality-wise, and its just that the versioning systems are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the versioning strategy for docker changed at some point.

> 17.03.0-ce 2017-03-01
>
> IMPORTANT: Starting with this release, Docker is on a monthly release
>   cycle and uses a new YY.MM versioning scheme to reflect this. Two
>   channels are available: monthly and quarterly. Any given monthly
>   release will only receive security and bugfixes until the next monthly
>   release is available. Quarterly releases receive security and bugfixes
>   for 4 months after initial release. This release includes bugfixes for
>   1.13.1 but there are no major feature additions and the API version stays the same. Upgrading from Docker 1.13.1 to 17.03.0 is expected to
>   be simple and low-risk.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/.

> For consistency, we are also renaming the free Docker products to
>   Docker Community Edition (CE) and adopting a new lifecycle and
>   time-based versioning scheme for both Docker EE and CE. Today’s Docker
>   CE and EE 17.03 release is the first to use the new scheme.

See https://blog.docker.com/2017/03/docker-enterprise-edition/.

Answer (score 1):

For both systems, I'm now installing docker software directly from the docker repositories and so have identical versions on both systems.

Instructions at:

- [Get Docker Engine - Community for CentOS](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-using-the-repository)
- [Get Docker Engine - Community for Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository)

Now the two systems (CentOS and Ubuntu) are in sync w.r.t. docker version.

Output of `docker version` on both yield an identical result:

```
# docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.5
 Git commit:        74b1e89
 Built:             Thu Jul 25 21:21:07 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.1
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.5
  Git commit:       74b1e89
  Built:            Thu Jul 25 21:19:36 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.6
  GitCommit:        894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8
  GitCommit:        425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```